# Удаление похожих элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите скрипт на удаления дубликатов нод, где ссылки совпадают.

```
<span class="title"><a href="/artist/Linkin Park/"><b>Linkin Park</b> - 7 раз</a></span>
```

Вместе с родителем:

```
<div class="play-music ">
    <h2 class="play-title"><span class="title"><a href="/artist/Linkin Park/"><b>Linkin Park</b></a> – <a href="http://muzlive.net/8-linkin-park-in-the-end.html">In the end</a></span></h2>
</div>
<div class="play-music ">
    <h2 class="play-title"><span class="title"><a href="/artist/Linkin Park/"><b>Linkin Park</b></a> – <a href="http://muzlive.net/9-linkin-park-in-the-end.html">In the end</a></span></h2>
</div>
```

Как удалить одинаковые строчки, которые есть в классе `<span class="title">`?
Т. е удалить все от `<div class="play-music ">` до `</div>`.

Comment: "Объяснил как смог)" - не является оправданием. Здесь не детский сад. Что Вам надо удалить?

Comment: Поддержу оратора выше. Нужно удалить дубли с одинаковыми ссылками?

Comment: Исправил выше. Гляньте

Comment: Одинаковость считается по какому параметру (ссылка, текст элемента, класс, атрибут)? Насколько надо удалять (сам элемент, родительский (до какого уровня))?

Comment: Ссылка и текст. Удалить похожие элементы от <div class="play-music "> до </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var $all = $(".play-music a[href='/artist/Linkin Park/']").closest(".play-music");
$all.not($all.eq(0)).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="play-music ">
  <h2 class="play-title"><span class="title"><a href="/artist/Linkin Park/"><b>Linkin Park</b></a> – <a href="http://muzlive.net/8-linkin-park-in-the-end.html">In the end</a></span></h2>
</div>
<div class="play-music ">
  <h2 class="play-title"><span class="title"><a href="/artist/Linkin Park/"><b>Linkin Park</b></a> – <a href="http://muzlive.net/9-linkin-park-in-the-end.html">In the end</a></span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно удалить, два, но оставить один. Удалить просто дубликаты

Comment: @razmenyairu, заюзайте в выборке `.splice(1)` и останется первый.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @razmenyairu добавьте загрузку библиотеки jQuery в страницу, как в начале ответа

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: @Other - хотите 17.5 очков?

Comment: Смотря чего, как и что мне надо для это сделать :)

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы работает, в общем работает ..удалил элементы с url group/iren

```js
var texts = [];
    $('a').each(function() {
        if (texts.indexOf($(this).text()) == -1) {
             texts.push($(this).text())
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('to-remove');
        }
    })
    $('a.to-remove').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/group/still">still</a>
<a href="/group/dooring">dooring</a>
<a href="/group/iren">iren</a>
<a href="/group/list">list</a>
<a href="/group/knoupf">knoupf</a>
<a href="/group/iren">iren</a>
<a href="/group/zoop">zoop</a>
<a href="/group/dzen">dzen</a>
<a href="/group/iren">iren</a>
<a href="/group/hu">hu</a>
```